# django __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given

Tags: python-3.x, django

My model class:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    campaign_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Campaign, self).__init__(self)
        self.campaign_id = generate_random_id(8) # it generates just random string

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My view class:

```
def campaign_list(request):
    campaigns = Campaign.objects.order_by('name').all()
    return render(request, 'mp/campaign/list.html', {'campaigns': campaigns})
```

I got error

> **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given

Before creating init in my model everything were working fine. But i assume that now Campaing.object.all() is using constructor and not **str**. How can i omit this and in .all still use just referring to name, not creating an object again?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by overriding the `__init__()` method?

Comment: To dynamically generate campaign id with my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**why this is happening**

I was getting the Below Error:

`Response.__init__() take one positional argument but 2 were given`

consider the example below having a `function` in `views.py` and `returning` the **Response**

but when I used the `auto import` extension in `visual studio`
[image: Image Example]

Accidently I Imported the `Response` class from the `requests` module instead of `rest_framework`

```
# example 
from requests import Response
#from rest_framework.response import Response

def hello_world_view(request):
    return Response('ok')
```

**Response class from request module**
[image: Response class from request module]

*having 1 position argument*

**Response class from rest_framework**
[image: Response class from rest_framework]
*can have many position argument*

Answer (score 3):

It may work to pass *args, **kwargs as arguments in the **init**.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # dont have to pass self
    self.campaign_id = generate_random_id(8) # it generates just random string
```

You can also override the save method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.campaign_id = generate_random_id(8)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: ```campaign_id = models.CharField(default=generate_random_id(8), max_length=8, unique=True)```
Will not work, beacuse it will affect in migrations. And every campaign id will be with same generated id.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I believe it works when you do not call the fuction like data=models.Datefield(default=timezone.now). That way it call the fuction everytime a object is created. But since your fuction takes a argument I don't think is possible to do it this way.

Comment: If generate_random_id function takes always the same argument, that argument should be removed and be stored in a variable inside the function

Answer (score 1):

Override save method instead of the initializer:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    campaign_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.campaign_id = generate_random_id(8)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```